# Spring Data JPA: Managing and mocking optional records

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I just want to make sure I am not going crazy but the bolded method would evaluate if NO booking exists in the Repo correct? I am running tests and the exception is being thrown when the mocked id is passed.

```
public class BookingServices {

    @Autowired
    BookingRepo bookingRepo;

    public Booking findBookingByBookingID(long bookingID) {
        if (! bookingRepo.existsById(bookingID)) {
            log.error("Booking not found");
            throw new BookingException("Booking not found");
        }

        return bookingRepo.findById(bookingID).get();
    }


**
```

> Testing class

**

```
 class BookingServicesTest {
    
        @InjectMocks
        private BookingServices bookingServices;
    
        @Mock
        private BookingRepo mockRepo;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void init(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
    
        @Test
        void findBookingByBookingID() {
            LocalDate bookingDate= LocalDate.of(2020,6,9);
            LocalDateTime scheduledDate =LocalDate.of(2020,7,4).atTime(6,30);
    
            Booking booking = new Booking();
            booking.setUserId(12345);
            booking.setBookingDate(bookingDate);
            booking.setScheduleDateTime(scheduledDate);
    
            Mockito.when(mockRepo.findById(5L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(booking));
    
            System.out.println(mockRepo.findById(5L));
            assertEquals(Optional.of(booking),bookingServices.findBookingByBookingID(5L));
        }
```

Comment: You could just call `return bookingRepo.findById(bookingID).orElseThrow(BookingException::new);` Then you only need one call to the database.

Comment: That is actually a great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, *findById()* returns the *Optional* modal, we can use *or, orElse, orElseThrow, ifPresent* etc. Here you may use orElseThrow as you are using `BookingException`. You can remove `existsById()` as follows

```
public Booking findBookingByBookingID(long bookingID) {
    return bookingRepo.findById(bookingID).orElseThrow(() -> new  BookingException("Booking not found"));
}
```